# $(this) not working with DragDealerjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, dragdealer-js

I am using DragdealerJS to trigger several actions and need the last left action ( when x is less than 0.00001 ) to make the individual div blue. I know this is a binding issue of some sort but I have not been able to solve the problem for the last few hours. Does anyone know how to get around this issue? Thanks for you help.

```
$(function() {
    new Dragdealer('demo-simple-slider', {
        x: 0.5,
        animationCallback: function(x, y) {
            if (x < 0.00001) {
                $(this).css('background-color', 'blue');
            } else if (x < 0.3) {
                $(".dragdealer").css('background-color', '#00cf48');
                $(".dragdealer").addClass('dragEdit');
            } else if (x > 0.99999) {
                $('.dragdealer').css('background-color', 'red');
                $('.dragdealer').parent().slideUp("slow");
            } else if (x > 0.7) {
                $('.dragdealer').css('background-color', 'red');
                $('.dragdealer').addClass('dragTrash');

            } else {
                $('.dragdealer').css('background-color', 'white');
                $('.dragdealer').removeClass('dragTrash');
                $('.dragdealer').removeClass('dragEdit');
            }
        }
     });
});
```

Here's the HTML if it helps.

```
<div id="demo-simple-slider" class="dragdealer">
    Scene
    <div class="handle red-bar"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason of the issue is because of this. In the `animationCallback` function `this` refers to the DragDealer **instance**, but in your case you want to access the DragDealer **element**.

To access it you can use `this.handle` property.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Irvin. I saw that as I was debugging and suspected as such but wasn't 100% sure. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue and it was a scoping one. I don't fully understand scoping yet but it is starting to make sense. If anyone has any good resources on learning more about scoping I'd love to see them.

```
$(function() {
  new Dragdealer('demo-simple-slider', {
      x: 0.5,
      animationCallback: function(x, y) {
          self = this;

          if (x < 0.00001) {

              console.log(self.handle);
              $(self.handle).css('background-color', 'blue');
          } else if (x < 0.3) {
              $(".dragdealer").css('background-color', '#00cf48');
              $(".dragdealer").addClass('dragEdit');
          } else if (x > 0.99999) {
              $('.dragdealer').css('background-color', 'red');
              $('.dragdealer').parent().slideUp("slow");
          } else if (x > 0.7) {
              $('.dragdealer').css('background-color', 'red');
              $('.dragdealer').addClass('dragTrash');

          } else {
              $('.dragdealer').css('background-color', 'white');
              $('.dragdealer').removeClass('dragTrash');
              $('.dragdealer').removeClass('dragEdit');

          }
      }
  });
});
```